# swipe to delete on cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Getting this error while trying to implement the swipe to delete 
i m a beginner so dont a help with an explanation will be good 
my todo list saved file
import Foundation

```
class TodoListsaved {
class var sharedInstance : TodoListsaved {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : TodoListsaved = TodoListsaved ()
    }

    return Static.instance
}
```

}

the cell func

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath   indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    let item = todoItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.toDoItem = item
    return cell

    //modify the cell to have check mark
    if (item.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

    else {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    }



  return cell
}
```

my datasource

import UIKit

```
class DataSource: NSObject {

let itenName: String
var completed : Bool
var deadline : NSDate
var UUID :String

init(itenName :String , completed :Bool = false , deadline : NSDate , UUID :String  ) {
    self.itenName = itenName
    self.completed = completed
    self.UUID = UUID
    self.deadline = deadline
    //self.subTitle = subTitle
    }
```

}
[image]

Comment: have u declared the toDoItem var at the cell class file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TableViewCell class change the variable toDoItem to type DataSource as follows:

```
class TablViewCell: UITableViewCell {
 var toDoItem: DataSource?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declared 'TableViewCell' Check that the type of property toDoItem is set to the class you are intending to. Also check the type of the array todoItems. They should be same but When I see your bug messages they are not same to each other.